# VB.Net Set AllowZeroLength Property in MS Access Table to No Using Create Table Query

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

How do I set a certain field's property AllowZeroLength to No? I'm making a table through query with the CREATE TABLE command. I do not know how to change AZL to No. I want to set col2 to not allow zero length. Last note: I'm going to use the query in VB.Net.

```
 CREATE TABLE table_name(
 col1 TEXT(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 col2 TEXT(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(col1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to HansUp's answer, the following VB.NET code uses DAO to update the `.AllowZeroLength` property for the field named [UserName] in the [Users] table:

```
' Note: This code requires the following COM reference:
'
' Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
'
Dim dbe As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine
Dim db As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database = dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\__tmp\testData.accdb")
db.TableDefs("Users").Fields("UserName").AllowZeroLength = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Access DDL does not provide a way to set the `AllowZeroLength` property.
But you can use DAO to set that property after you execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```vb
CurrentDb.TableDefs("table_name").Fields("col2").AllowZeroLength = False
```

Comment: Could you give an example in VB.NET? I'm using VB.Net and I'm not familiar with ADO. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't know VB.Net.  Add that requirement to your question and you should probably also tag the question as such.